# How to open a file within python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that takes student names and saves into a file but i'm getting issue with opening file.

Below is the code snippet.

```
students = []

def get_students_titlecase():
    students_titlecase = []
    for student in students:
        students_titlecase.append(student["name"].title())
    return students_titlecase


def print_students_titlecase():
    students_titlecase = get_students_titlecase()
    print (students_titlecase)


def add_student(name, student_id):
    student = {"name": name , "student_id": student_id}
    students.append(student)


def save_file(student):
    try:
        f = open("students.txt", "a")
        f.write(student + "\n")
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("couldn't open the file")


def read_file():
    try:
        f = open("students.txt", "r")
        for student in f.readlines():
            add_student(student)
        f.close()
    except Exception:
        print("couldn't read file")


read_file()
print_students_titlecase()

student_name = input("Enter the student name: ")
student_id = input("Enter the student_id: ")

add_student(student_name, student_id)
save_file(students)
```

Output:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/arunyantrapragada/PycharmProjects/FirstProg/function.py
[]
Enter the student name: thomas

Enter the student_id: 456

couldn't open the file

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: what is your question? what is your problem??

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Can you add what kind of errors do you have ? Also can you add where your code is broken ?

Comment: Hey Mureinik, please check the output so that you can have a clear idea. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/arunyantrapragada/PycharmProjects/FirstProg/function.py
[]
Enter the student name: thomas
Enter the student_id: 456
couldn't open the file

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: did the file exist in your project's folder path ?

Comment: Yes it is there.

Comment: The code is suppose to take the student name and Id as Input and should store the name in "student.txt" file. But i'm getting exception that file couldn't not be open after taking the inputs. My code is breaking at "save_file()" fucnction.

Comment: Are you executing the program from the same directory where the `students.txt` file is located?

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason a try/catch block is often ill-advised. Your error was not that the file could not be opened, but instead that this line was throwing an error:

```
f.write(student + "\n")
```

`+` does not append a dictionary (`student`) and a string (`\n`). Your try/catch block is reporting this as an open file error.